# Unable to find Table in Azure Mobile Service Win Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I am currently trying to implement `Azure Mobile Service` into my `Windows Phone 8.1` application. 
I followed documentation on it Azure.Microsoft.com:
[Get started with Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/) and I created a new Windows Phone 8.1 project with the service. I tried making a new table with the exact configuration as the sample as well as a new `Class` to matching the table name & fields. Below is the original code, I changed all of the TodoItem into 'Test'

I keep getting the error:

> Error: Table 'Test' does not exist

I tried making both a `Javascript` and `.NET` version for back-end but they still failed
Am I unable to find my table because I am missing a step?

```
sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private MobileServiceCollection<Test, Test> items;
    private IMobileServiceTable<Test> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Test>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task InsertTodoItem(Test todoItem)
    {
        await todoTable.InsertAsync(todoItem);
        items.Add(todoItem);
    }

    private async Task RefreshTodoItems()
    {
        MobileServiceInvalidOperationException exception = null;
        try
        {
            items = await todoTable
                .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false)
                .ToCollectionAsync();
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        if (exception != null)
        {
            await new MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Error loading items").ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            ListItems.ItemsSource = items;
            this.ButtonSave.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    private async Task UpdateCheckedTodoItem(Test item)
    {
        await todoTable.UpdateAsync(item);
        items.Remove(item);
        ListItems.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused);
    }

    private async void ButtonRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonRefresh.IsEnabled = false;
        await RefreshTodoItems();

        ButtonRefresh.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private async void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var todoItem = new Test { Text = TextInput.Text };
        await InsertTodoItem(todoItem);
    }

    private async void CheckBoxComplete_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
        Test item = cb.DataContext as Test;
        await UpdateCheckedTodoItem(item);
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await RefreshTodoItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code from your .NetBackend: controllers, dtos, model, dbContext... I think I know the issue but need to see the code, first, update your original post with it.

Comment: @saramgsilva may I know where can I check that? I am new to this sorry and thank you.

Comment: Where is the code from you Backend? The code you provided is for the client application and not for the backend

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript backend:

Go into the azure portal and select your mobile service. Go to the tab that says data. Click add a table name the table Test.

For .Net:

Open the project in Visual Studio. Add your Test class to the DataObjects folder. Right click the Controllers folder -> add -> controller. Select Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Table Controller. Chose your Test class for the model class and there should only be one option for the data context class.

Answer (score 0):

You follow this article

[Get started with Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/)

and you saw this

[image]

and with this you got the source code. This way you got two projects:

- The .Net BackEnd project
- The client app project

and when you did the changes, you only changed the client app project (because the MainPage belongs to the client app).

If you changed the TodoItem class to Test class in client app project, you need to do the same for the .NET Project, which requires the changes:

- change the TodoItemController to TestController
- change the TodoItem to Test

do a clean, then build and if do not have any error you can publish to Azure.

To help understand a bit it, I recommend to see the following samples

- [Connecting a Menu App to Azure Mobile Service](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/microsoft-windows-app-studio-beta-connecting-a-menu-app-to-azure-mobile-service/)

this article contains a step by step to create a simple backend like you are doing and provides tips that will help you.

- [How to create the Azure Mobile Service in Azure Portal](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/how-to-create-the-azure-mobile-service-in-azure-portal/)
- [AzureMobileServices: Samples to help developers to use Azure Mobile Services](http://saramgsilva.github.io/AzureMobileServices/)